# How to split a list on multiple commas and spaces

Tags: algorithm, text-files

I am trying to split this line in a text file so that the ArrayList is `[Node_01, 1, Node_02,1 ...etc]`.

I  tried multiple methods including

```
str.split("\\s"), str.split("\\s*), str.split("\\s*, \\s*)
```

and none worked.

The ArrayList is shown below:

```
[Node_01 1, Node_02 1, Node_03 1, Node_04 1, Node_05 1, Node_06 1, Node_07 1, Node_08 1, Node_09 1, Node_10 1, Node_11 1]
```

Comment: Have you tried str.split("\") ?

Comment: `str.split("[\\s,]+")`